# Post JSONObject and get JSONArray request Volley

Tags: android, json, post, android-volley

I am currently trying to post a JsonObject to my API and get a JsonArray response from the server. How would i go about that? I get an exception error if i try

```
JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_test,new JSONObject(params),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
```

Comment: would you please tell which `Exception` is thrown?

Comment: post the crash log and full code..

Comment: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException:

Comment: I know what is going wrong. I am getting a JSONArray as a response and parsing it like a JsonObject. My question is how would i use volley to create a post request which posts a JsonObject and listens for a JsonArray.

Comment: You just need to Make json array request as you expect an array coming back. What data you post does not matter i believe -- http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/ -- http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

Comment: i know that i have to make a json array request. But i want to send a json object along with the request but i cannot with the Json array request method

Answer (score 0):

Try these..

```
  url = "http://your Api post";
    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, 
        new Response.Listener<String>() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // response
                Log.d("Response", response);
            }
        }, 
        new Response.ErrorListener() 
        {
             @Override
             public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                 // error
                 Log.d("Error.Response", response);
           }
        }
    ) {  

//You send the key and value to server you enter here   


 @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() 
    {  
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();  
            params.put("key", "value");  

            return params;  
    }
};
queue.add(postRequest);
```